# Invoking multiple member functions of an object/class during object/class creation

Tags: c++

I didnt know this was possible to do in C++, until I saw it. 
AddAttribute(),AddTraceSource(),etc are member functions of the class TypeId.

```
TypeId
Sender::GetTypeId (void)
{
static TypeId tid = TypeId ("Sender")
.SetParent<Application> () /*Member function of TypeId*/
.AddConstructor<Sender> () 
.AddAttribute ("PacketSize") 
.AddAttribute ("Destination") 
.AddTraceSource ("Tx")
;
return tid;
}
```

I never knew we could do this in C++. **Could someone please throw more light on this topic (calling multiple member functions during object creation)?**  I know we can do this in scripting. But in c++? The file had an extension *.cc. Sorry if my question is naive, and it turns out I missed out on reading a few chapters in C++?!

Comment: Where did you take this code from? It's hard to understand what it does without any further context.

Comment: Thanks for all your replies! This code snippet is from ns3 simulator (nsnam.org)

Answer (score 3):

The key to this trick is that all of those member functions return a reference to the calling object.  So:

```
TypeId("Sender")
```

That calls the constructor, returning a temporary object.  Then:

```
.SetParent<Application>()
```

That calls the `SetParent<>` member function of the temporary `TypeId` object. It probably has a signature like this:

```
template<typename T>
TypeId & SetParent();
```

So, it returns a reference to the object on which it was invoked (`*this`), which allows the next call, to `AddConstructor<Sender>()`, and that function likely has a similar signature, as do the other functions in the chain.

Answer (score 1):

You can chain functions whenever you want and into whatever long chains you want, untill the functions return a reference to the object. That's what happens when you call the overloaded `operator <<` on the `std::cout` stream, and that's what you can code too in your class, in the same way.

The basic idea is in the class design. Instead of returnin `void` in every function, return a reference to the object, that called the function.

```
class sample{
   sample& fun1(){cout << "fun1" << endl; return *this;};
   sample& fun2(int number){cout << "fun2("<<number<")\n"; return *this;};
   sample& fun3(){cout << "fun3" << endl; return *this;};
};
```

Now you can call functions like this:

```
sample yourObject;
yourObject.fun1().fun2(5).fun3().fun1().fun2(12);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is known as the builder pattern.

This isn't some sort of special language feature; instead, the functions are returning references to the object they were invoked on.

Each of these functions has a return type of `TypeId&`, and they're just returning `*this`, so the caller can chain together many functions in a single statement.

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing is a design pattern known as the [builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern).

Each of the methods that set something mutates some internal state and then returns a reference to `*this`, allowing further calls to be made on the same object.

Finally and conceptually, we store the object returned by the last call, `AddTraceSource`, in `tid`. Since all the preceding functions returned a reference to the same instance, we'll store the same instance that the constructor created initially.

Thus, `SetParent` is probably implemented along the following lines

```
template <typename T>
TypeId& TypeId::SetParent()
{
    this->parent = T();
    return *this;
}
```

You've probably encountered this pattern in other places as well. Iostreams do this as well with their `<<` and `>>` operators.

```
std::cout << "Here's one call to the overloaded operator."
          << " Here's another."
          << " Take a look at the signature of operator<< when you get chance."
          << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is totally possible to chain functions:

```
//foo() returns string
auto size = foo().length();
```

These functions can be chained if they each return a `&TypeId` (`*this`) type: just shorthand.